# Spring RestController removes "is" from property name

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I have an object with the property isTechnician. If I return this object via a Spring RestController the property in the http response json is named technician.
Why does spring cut of the is? How can I disable it?

```
@Document
public class User {
...
private boolean isTechnician;

...

public boolean isTechnician() {
    return isTechnician;
}

public void setTechnician(boolean technician) {
    isTechnician = technician;
}
}
```

RestController

```
@GetMapping("user")
public List<User> GetUsers() {
    var query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(where("disabled").is(false));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the class with getters and setters

Comment: Good hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution of this problem is to use annotation @JsonProperty on your getter function.

```
@JsonProperty("isTechnician")
public boolean isTechnician() {
    return isTechnician;
}
```

Now your JSON will become

```
{
    "isTechnician":true
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Better solution

Answer (score 1):

By default jackson had visibility on getters and setters while serialization and deserialization, so just disable that by using JsonAutoDetect

```
 @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isTechnician` getter isn't compliant with the standards. You should name it `isIsTechnician` or `getIsTechnician` (since the field property is called `isTechnician`)

**or**

annotate your field with `@JsonProperty("isTechnician")`.

Jackson (the default Spring JSON parser) will *ignore* getter name (from which it gets the corresponding JSON key name) and use the one specified as value in `@JsonProperty` annotation.